# Cross-platform MySQL database backup using mysqldump

Tags: php, mysql, windows, laravel

In a Laravel (PHP framework) project, we implemented a backup feature - backing up user-generated files and database tables. What we've searched so far, the best solution in backing up mysql database is to run the `mysqldump` command.

So we made the command:

```
<?php
$storage_path = 'path/to/backups';
$database = env('DB_DATABASE');
$user     = env('DB_USERNAME');
$pass     = env('DB_PASSWORD');
$host     = env('DB_HOST');
$dir_file = "{$storage_path}/{now()->timestamp}-database.sql.gzip";

$backup_cmd = "mysqldump --user={$user} --password={$pass} --host={$host} {$database} | gzip > {$dir_file}";

// Run the command and take the backup.
exec( $backup_cmd, $output, $mysql_backup_status );
```

In our **MS Windows development environment**, we got the errors:

```
dump($output);
array(
   "'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command",
   "operable program or batch file."
)
```

The issue is, path to `mysqld` or `mysqldump` is not in the system PATH. After adding the path to PATH and restarting the system the command works fine and take backup.

To make the solution cross-platform-friendly we took an initiative to check whether the command `mysqldump` is available or not, if not we'll gonna take the path to `mysqldump.exe` from the user.
[image: mysqldump-path-field-for-user-to-input]

And with user input we will change the command like below:

```
// Check default way - the PATH.
exec( 'mysqldump --version 2>&1', $output, $return_val );
if( $return_val != 0 ) {
   //mysqldump in undefined, so get the user defined path to it
   $path = "C:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-5.7.19-winx64\bin"; //get as user input
   $mysqldump = "{$path}\mysqldump.exe";
} else {
   $mysqldump = 'mysqldump';
}

$backup_cmd = "{$mysqldump} --user={$user} --password={$pass} --host={$host} {$database} | gzip > {$dir_file}";

// Run the command and take the backup.
exec( $backup_cmd, $output, $mysql_backup_status );
```

With this measure the code is working well in both the cases:

- `mysqldump` is in PATH
- `mysqldump` is in NOT in PATH

In our mini test unit it worked. But I wonder:

- **Is it a balanced way of doing this?**
  Means, the workaround we did (with all the UI/UX, unwanted trailing slash removal, using of `exec()` etc.) to simply check how we can run `mysqldump` without glitch - are we doing good? Or, simply making an easy thing critical?
- **Is the code cross-OS-friendly?**

---

**PS**:
We're checking `--version` but finally executing backup command, because running backup command for testing *executes it* even with PHP [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function, and create a backup file, and we don't want that. We took `exec()` over `system()` as it's `$output` and `$return_value` seemed more reliable and silent than of `system()`.

### Edit

With the answer by baot a good point came into view, the unescaped user-provided data into `exec()` command. I's aware about it, but finally forgot it to escape.

I now escaped the user input with `escapeshellarg()` before using 'em into the `exec()`:

```
// escape unwanted shell command
$mysqldump = escapeshellarg($mysqldump);

$backup_cmd = "{$mysqldump} --user={$user} --password={$pass} --host={$host} {$database} | gzip > {$dir_file}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is the code cross-OS-friendly?**

Sure it is working, but IMHO one should *never* use `exec()` especially in costumer software with user supplied data to it. I'am gueesing you have to logged in to a admin account but still it's a huge security risk. But if you insist on using it, you should at a minimum check that the user supplied path is a vaild path and do a md5 hash of `mysqldump`.

I would just use a php native solution like [mysqldump-php](https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php) instead of using `exec()`.

**Is it a balanced way of doing this?**

You have solved the problem in a simple way, so thats good. The only thing i can see as a hurdle is if you have costumers that isn't that tech savvy. it could be hard for them to find the correct path and/or knowing if mysqldump is installed.

<del>could you flesh out this question further, i dont understand what you are asking? (cant comment yet)</del>

Comment: Upvote for already making a good point. I updated my question with a lot of thanks.

Comment: _if you have costumers that isn't that tech savvy. it could be hard for them to find the correct path and/or knowing if mysqldump is installed._ - Yes, as a WordPress developer I'm well aware that our clients are not always that much _techy_. And in that case it's a bad idea. But don't worry, in our case we'll deploy the app most of the time. Thank you for your time.